# Running Multiple Rails Apps on Single Nginx with Subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, subdomain

I'm trying to figure out how to get a 2nd Rails app running on my server under a subdomain. Here's my setup:

(App1) Primary Rails app -> http://humani.se

(App2) Secondary Rails app -> http://supportme.humani.se

The domain name is purchased through GoDaddy, and currently I have the subdomain pointing to http://humani.se:3000 (through the GoDaddy panel), which you can see works by just visiting that URL. I know, I know -- App1 is running in production and App2 is running in development, not good practice. I'm just trying to see if I can get it working.

Nginx Conf:

```
# Primary Application Server
upstream humanise {
  # for UNIX domain socket setups:
  server unix:/home/jeff/srv/humani.se/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
  # server localhost:8080;
}

server {
  server_name humani.se www.humani.se;

  # path for static files
  root /home/jeff/srv/humani.se/public;

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @humanise;

  location @humanise {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    # proxy_pass http://unix:/home/jeff/srv/humani.se/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock;
    proxy_pass http://humanise;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}

# Secondary Application Server
upstream supportme {
  server localhost:3000;
}

server {
  server_name supportme.humani.se;

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @supportme;

  location @supportme {
    proxy_pass http://supportme;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_buffering off;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Looks like it works, right? Nope! So all the routes seem to work EXCEPT from the Rails side. If you attempt to login (with any/no credentials), you will see the error, too. Basically, the URL helpers aren't working from the controller side. The ones in the views (anchor hyperlinks) work perfectly fine. From the server log:

```
Started POST "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-20 13:51:56 -0400
Processing by UsersController#login as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",     "authenticity_token"=>"eJvcm5auwCWFzw2BRY8DLzv8W5I3z0W529MXAJRLJb0=", "user"=>{"email"=>"ijt", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'ijt' LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://supportme.humani.se/
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)


Started GET "/.humani.se/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-20 13:51:56 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/.humani.se"):
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /home/jeff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/jeff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/jeff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

You can clearly see it's redirecting to the correct URL but then gets /.humani.se/ instead. Someone somewhere must know about this!

Any and all help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
  - Jeff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you should not let godaddy point to the port, point both `humani.se` and `supportme.humani.se` to the same IP, and let nginx redirect each to the right app, like you can run app1 on port `3000` and app2 on port `3001` then do a simply proxy on nginx

```
server {
  server_name humani.se;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
  }
}
server {
  server_name support.humani.se;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
  }
}
```

this should do the trick, tell me what you get.

Comment: You rock! Thanks, man! Configuring all this stuff isn't my forté. Points for you!